# dpkg: command not found in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dpkg

How can I resolve the `dpkg command not found` in Ubuntu 16.04?

**Tried 1:**

```
root@mine:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo: dpkg: command not found
```

**Tried 2**

```
root@mine:~# dpkg --configure -a
The program 'dpkg' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install dpkg
```

**Tried 3**

```
root@mine:~# apt install dpkg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dpkg is already the newest version (1.18.4ubuntu1.2).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 android-emulator : Depends: ubuntu-emulator-runtime but it is not installable
                    Depends: ubuntu-emulator-images but it is not installable
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2) but it is not installable
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: What led to this situation?

Comment: Just type `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and tell us if it goes

Comment: root@mine:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a, Then 
"sudo: dpkg: command not found @Melebius"

Comment: @udayakumar Wait, you are in a root shell? How did you get there? And you can leave `sudo` out while in a root shell.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working @answerSeeker

Comment: @udayakumar, can you install anything with apt?? If so, try to install dpkg. If not, grab the deb from http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Comment: before downloading and installing anything try this:  `sudo /usr/bin/dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Now, I tried this "root@mine:~# dpkg --configure -a", It return for "The program 'dpkg' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install dpkg", Then  using this "root@mine:~#apt install dpkg" and it reuturns at "dpkg is already the newest version (1.18.4ubuntu1.2).

Comment: Please add all details [into your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/924621/edit), not comments. And you should answer George’s and my questions.